# Server side rendering of Kendo chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I need to send scheduled mails to my user. In this mail I need to show charts ( preferably Kendo Chart ). I have the data but have no idea about generating attachment of graph on fly on server side. How can I achieve this.

I created a sample html page with kendo chart. tried converting this html screen to pdf using online tool. But Kendo takes longer to render chart. And therefore this results in a blank page.

Answer (score -2):

You can use saveAsPDF or excelExport functions:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").saveAsPDF();
```

or

```
$('#grid').getKendoGrid().saveAsExcel();
```

you can also add the function to your grid definition:

```
excelExport: function (e) {
        e.workbook.fileName = "Grid.xlsx";
    },
```

[Here is how to export to a server path](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet/configuration/excel)

Hope it helps

Comment: The main problem is to generate kendo grid or chart on server side. As it will be a script that will be running on its own. And there will be no user interaction in that.

Comment: As the rendering happens in the browser, you would have to use a rendering engine and capture the result on the server.

I never did something like that. Maybe the Progress report server is the better tool for that.